# Top Questions of the Week #6

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 6 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each we week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to blow my own trumpet but the [HP CPU Assassin](https://superuser.com/questions/240794/why-does-wmi-provider-host-wmiprvse-exe-keep-spiking-my-cpu) (thanks @nhinkle for the title) and [Browser Addon to filter Google search results](https://superuser.com/questions/245959/is-there-a-browser-addon-to-filter-google-search-results) are both good.

Answer (score -1):

I motion to include [Is there any product to prevent a broken screen's pieces from falling from it?](https://superuser.com/questions/246365/is-there-any-product-to-prevent-a-broken-screens-pieces-from-falling-from-it) because of the ridiculousness of the answer.

Comment: Although this is interesting, the answer doesn't seem to be that "novel" in my opinion.  We'll see what the rest of the community thinks.

Comment: lulz[.](http://sathyabh.at)